# Where can I get the JSONRequestError code?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Following the [JSONRequest proposa](http://www.json.org/JSONRequest.html)l, I've found [code for the JSONRequest object](http://www.devpro.it/code/153.html). However, this object depends on JSONRequestError, and the code for that is nowhere to be found.

Anyone know where I can find the code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the request `JSONRequestError site:devpro.it` in Google, it is a useful tip... ^_^

Found [JSONRequestError.js](http://www.devpro.it/JSON/files/JSONRequestError-js.html) which explain the API, and ... hmm, no source code!

Just poked around the magical number 153, got lucky: [JSONRequestError.js](http://www.devpro.it/code/152.html) :-D

Answer (score 2):

For such a highly spoke of and nicely documented library, finding the download link is ridiculous but here goes:

- [JSONRequest.javascript](http://devpro.it/javascript_id_152.html)
- [JSONRequestError.javascript](http://devpro.it/javascript_id_153.html)

(The second  as the guy said in a hard to understand kind of way - all coders seem to half explain things!)